# I need help writing this program. I have no idea how to do it to be honest. Here's the prompt

Tags: python-2.7

Write a program that prompts the user for the radius and height of a 3-dimensional cone and then
calculates and prints the surface area and volume of the cone. The calculation of the surface area
and the volume will be done in functions, as will the gathering of the inputs

Comment: break the problem down.  Which steps can you do?

Comment: I know how to prompt the question, but that's about it. I've never used python before, but I've used Java Script.

Comment: "I've never used python before,"  -erm, then go learn it!

Comment: totally would, but this is due in about 2 hours :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
def surfaceAreaOfCone(radius, height):
return math.pi * radius * (radius + math.sqrt(height * height + radius * radius))

def volumeOfCone(radius, height):
    return math.pi * (radius * radius) * height/3

radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius: "))
height = float(raw_input("Enter the height: "))
print("Surface Area:" + repr(surfaceAreaOfCone(radius, height)))
print("Volume: " + repr(volumeOfCone(radius, height)))
```